# How can I keep Firefox notifications on the notification center on Ubuntu 18:04

Tags: gnome, firefox, 18.04, notification

Every time the browser sends me a notification, it only lasts for a moment, then it disappears. I would like to make them disappear by clicking on them (whatsapp web notifications, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The notification only disappears after you move your mouse or type something. If you go away from your computer the notifications will still be showing when you come back.

For notifications that have disappeared you can click the date on your top bar and it will show a list of the last few notifications so you can read them again. You will see a dot next to the date when there are new notifications.

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph: that doesn't seem to be the case. My web push notifications appear, disappear, then I open the notification center and they're not there

Comment: OK well that is odd then. Perhaps it's one particular app that's misbehaving? I don't know, I'm just guessing now sorry.

Comment: Well, it's normal Firefox, latest version on Ubuntu 18.04, regular sites that send push. Is that not the case for you?

Comment: I use FF and I haven't noticed any push notifications appear via Gnome at all, I could be wrong. I wouldn't want them to anyway. It's like my emails, they pop up but they don't save, if they did then my notifications panel would fill up with clutter pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop notifications can be made temporary by the app (the site) that creates them. I know for sure that GMail does that (at least to the present date). You can find a working example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) that creates a notification that does not disappear.

On the other hand, I'm trying to figure out why the notifications created in this way don't show the dot next to the date, in the Gnome panel.

Comment: The question isn't a developer's question, but rather a user's.