# How to prevent Google Chrome "native" notifications from disappearing?

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, gnome-shell, notification

I've enabled Chrome native notifications:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-native-notifications
```

When I get an web notification, it shows for a second on the top side and also in Ubuntu's notifications area (click on the clock or <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).

The problem is that it disappears even though I didn't "handle" it. I didn't click on it.

This causes me to lose track of pending stuff, like messages from co-workers.

Any idea how to keep the web notifications from disappearing?

Comment: Found a related question in Google's forum. Though the question is about Apple's notification center, it has the same issue as in Ubuntu, which suggests it's a chrome issue and not OS specific. Quesition: https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0FbDDWCQE4t0

Comment: Related:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035539/how-can-i-keep-firefox-notifications-on-the-notification-center-on-ubuntu-1804